# Swagger CodeGen for RestSharp Version 102.2.0

Tags: c#, swagger, restsharp, openapi-generator, swagger-codegen

I would like to ask if there is a Swagger tool that can generate clients according to the latest version of RestSharp (110.2.0). I've noticed that Swagger Codegen currently uses RestSharp version 102.2.3 to generate client code, and when using the latest version of RestSharp (110.2.0), I encounter the issue of having to manually edit the autogenerated client code. This isn't an ideal situation and also defeats the purpose of code autogeneration

I also attempted to use Swagger Codegen's web-based editor to generate sample code with the latest version of Swagger Codegen, but I  still encountered an issue of having to manually edit the auto-generated code when upgrading to the latest RestSharp version.

Comment: OpenAPI Generator `csharp` client generator supports RestSharp 110.2.0. We just released v7.0.1: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/releases/tag/v7.0.1. Please check it out when you've time.